# Python Loop and Range function

Tags: python, loops, range

Can anyone please explain this python code, how the answer is "5050" ?

```py
total = 0
for number in range(0, 101):
    total += number
print(total)
```

Comment: This is the sum of the first 100 integers from 0 to and including 100. Range(0,101) returns a list of integers [0,1,2...100]. So adding them all together results in 5050. The for loop iterates through the list and number variable is the current integer.

Answer (score 0):

what happen is when run the this code is the for loop going to add the number to the total variable
so in the first loop the total = 0 and the number = 0 so the total will equal to 0
in the second loop the total = 0 and the number = 1 so the total will equal to 1
in the second loop the total = 1 and the number = 2 so the total will equal to 3
and so on
in the last loop :
the total = 4950 and the number = 100 so the total will equal to 5050 and this is output you've got

hope you understood

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
total = 0
for number in range(0, 101):
    total = total + number
```

Initially total equals 0, range function range function sorts values from 0 to 101. The for loop adds 1 to the total value in the first step, At this stage the total is equal to 1, In the next step, the number 2 comes from the range function and adds 2 to the total value. Total is equal to 3 in the final case. The number produced by the range function is added to the total value each time. This situation continues until the for loop is completed and in the last step the total equals 5050. I hope I was able to explain.